# ReferenceError: Unknown option: .present

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

hello i just made environment setup for react js and it gives me error
`ReferenceError: Unknown option: .present.`  and here is codes of `.babelrc` `webpack.config.js`, `package.json` and `react.js` (file)

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './react.js',
output:{
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/frapp'),
    filename: 'bundled.js'
},
devServer:{
    inline: true,
    port: 8001
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
           test: /\.jsx?$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           query:{
             present:['es2015', 'react']
           }
        }
    ]
},
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "reacc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

for more details i would like to screenshot my directory here it is
[image]

here is part of error : Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
ReferenceError: Unknown option: .present. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/b
abel-core/#options for more information about options.

as a matter of fact, react is opens html page but does not display text in div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `presets`, not `present:['es2015', 'react']`. There's a typo in your `webpack.config.js`.

Also what's that `query` key?

```
query: {
   present:['es2015', 'react']
}
```

From what I know it should be `options`. So:

```
options: {
   presets: ['es2015', 'react']
}
```

Comment: ERROR in ./react.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from 'C:\Users\tuna\Desktop\reac
c'ERROR in ./react.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from '(pathname)'

Comment: There was a major upgrade from Webpack 3 to 4. Babel has also upgraded their preset inclusion logic. It's tough times to start configuring both from scratch, especially for bundling React applications. Consider using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) instead. It will do it all for you, and you will be able to concentrate on coding the actual app.

Comment: why should i start with create-react-app i can not get, it is more professional way? i got confused to be honest

Comment: If your goal is to learn, then go on with whatever gets in the way. But if you need to create an app, spending days on configuring the environment is pointless.

Comment: does that really matters? , i did things and i got really confused when i run command npm run build it created folder as i wanted but with index.html so i got  2 html file, i tried to delete html file that was not in fsrapp folder but it did not worked. i got really confused. if you work around react js, give me a best suggestion, is  create-react-app really best solution for personal or job projects? ?

Comment: create-react-app is for people who do not want to mess with webpack/babel configurations now and then. That's it. Personal, job - it doesn't matter. Facebook itself (folks behind ReactJS) created it to simplify the bootstrap procedure.

Comment: thank you very much for explanation and answer i am gonna mark it as correct